# chroot gentoo in usb

Tags: usb, gentoo, chroot

So I really tried to extract it but it gives me this error:

Command (extracted on usb):

```
tar xpvf stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20201021T14503Z --xattrs-include='*.*' --numeric-owner
```

Output:

```
tar: ./sys/: cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0 operation not permitted
```

And:

```
tar: ./bin/mount: Cannot change mode to rws--x--x: operation not permitted
```

Errors like that

Is there a way that can I chroot? In usb? (Note—I just want to chroot not install Gentoo).

---

### EDIT

After the comment of user Binki

Thanks

I changed the file system of my flash drive to EXT4.
And run the commands in the gentoo wiki and guess what? It worked.
Here's the list of command that I run to chroot
(For nomultilib):

```
tar xpvf stage3-amd64-nomultilib-20201021T14503Z --xattrs-include='*.*' --numeric-owner
```

Mounting file system:

```
mount --types proc /proc specified_usb/gentoo/proc
mount --rbind /sys specified_usb/gentoo/sys
mount --make-rslave specified_usb/gentoo/sys
mount --rbind /dev specified_usb/gentoo/dev
mount --make-rslave specified_usb/gentoo/dev
test -L /dev/shm && rm /dev/shm && mkdir /dev/shm
mount --types tmpfs --options nosuid,nodev,noexec shm /dev/shm
chmod 1777 /dev/shm
```

Comment: It sounds like either you are not running this as root (but you probably are) or you are using a non-unixy filesystem such as FAT on the USB drive. You can simply repartition and reformat the USB using a filesystem such as ext3. Now, if those are your only two errors, that may not be a big deal. You probably don’t need to use the `mount` command as a non-root user (which is what the `+s` is intended for) and you probably should be [bind-mounting the host system’s `/sys` over the `sys` folder](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation#Mounting_the_necessary_filesystems).

Comment: I'm running this as root

Comment: What filesystem is the flashdrive using?

Comment: Hi, I am moving my comment to an answer. Please consider accepting it if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you are root, you may still get errors like the following:

```
tar: ./sys/: cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0 operation not permitted
tar: ./bin/mount: Cannot change mode to rws--x--x: operation not permitted
```

These sound like permissions errors. And they might be in some cases. So note that you do need to be root for those commands to work.

However, those errors can also show up if the filesystem you are using does not support those features. For example, if the flashdrive is formatted as a variant of FAT32, it cannot support certain operations such as storing unix permissions. You can switch your flashdrive to use a filesystem which supports these operations such as EXT4 to proceed. Depending on your use case, you might want to create a loopback file on the flashdrive (so that the flashdrive itself can be kept FAT but the loopback EXT4).

When chrooting, be sure to remember to [bind mount filesystems as explained in the Gentoo handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation#Mounting_the_necessary_filesystems). Certain operations/programs will fail without things from at least `/dev`, `/sys`, and `/proc` mounted.